# Can I create single Dockerfile from laradock?

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I got instructed to create a single dockerfile in the root of the project, but also got a tip to use the laradock as starting point.

How can I do this? The only way so far I know to create an docker environment is to run it with docker-compose command

Comment: I have the same question, as it is not really clear how to organize the structure to build an image on Docker Hub. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No,** Dockerfiles are single containers (services) by design. Laradock provides a docker-compose file that references multiple dockerfiles. However you could create a smaller docker-compose file that only starts the containers you need (let's say a webserver with php, a database server and redis).

Laradock ships with way to much containers in docker-compose, that is why the [tutorial](https://laradock.io/getting-started/) tells you to specify which containers you want to run.

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql
```

But if you specify a minimal docker-compose.yml, you just can type

```
docker-compose up -d
```

without any additional arguments

---

**Yes,** you could add all the required services to a single container, but that would be against [what you try to achieve using Docker](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/when-and-why-to-use-docker/).

Comment: I already accepted the answer as correct but in the meanwhile I noticed that there is a concept of "Docker in Docker", so if I can create an image that hosts docker containers inside of it, am I actually able to do a containers that are built from laradock. Aren't I? It would be deployable as any other docker container with kubernetess so it is still following the design